# accidentally applied color profile

Tags: color-management

I accidentally applied a color profile to my display in the color application in system settings. I was wondering if any one knew how to revert this, as there is no revert option in the window. I am currently running 13.04 any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the color settings page, then click on the monitor and it should show you the profile in the right. Click on that profile and then remove it with the prompt. It should remove the profile immediately, but if not try logging out or rebooting.